# Keep Navigation Menu on Custom Taxonomy Archive Page When Viewing Custom Post Type Single

Tags: wordpress, menu, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

On my site, I have added a navigation menu with links to archives of a custom taxonomy («usage»). When clicking on a such link, all custom posts («buildings») are listed, as expected. The current menu item (the taxonomy term) is higlighted and ok.

[image: The custom taxonomy term "Wohnen" is highlighted, below is the list of the custom posts]

---

The menu is created in the menu-section as normal:

[image]

---

The code for the menu is as follows:

```
$sub_nav = wp_nav_menu( array(
                            'start_depth'    => 1,
                            'theme_location' => 'mainMenu',
                            'menu_class'     => '',
                            'menu_id'        => '',
                            'container'      => '',
                            'items_wrap'     => '%3$s',
                            'walker'         => new Uruk_Sub_Menu_Walker()
                        ) );
```

The code for the walker class is quite simple:

- I just wrap the `a`-elements in a `div`-element to keep a 2:1-ratio  -
- I don't want a newline after the `li`-element.
- Whenever a new level starts or ends, I don't add any wrappers

```
     /**
     * Menu-Walker für die Unternavigation
     *
     * Rechts neben dem Logo listet sich die Unternavigation auf
     *
     * @since 1.0
     */
    class Uruk_Sub_Menu_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

        /**
         * Item beginnen
         *
         * LI-Element für ein Navigationselement beginnen, mit eingemittetem
         * A-Element
         *
         * @since 1.0
         */
        function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth, $args ) {

            //$class_names = '';
            $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
            $classes[] = 'item-' . $item->ID;
            $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
            $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

            $output .= '<li' . $class_names .'>';

            // link attributes
            $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
            $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
            $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
            $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

            $output .= '<div class="sub-nav-item-ratio"></div>';
            $output .= sprintf( '%1$s<a%2$s>%3$s%4$s%5$s</a>%6$s',
                $args->before,
                $attributes,
                '<div class="link-text-height"></div><div class="link-text-wrapper">',
                apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ),
                '</div>',
                $args->after
            );
        }


        /**
         * Ende eines LI-Elements
         *
         * Diesmal ohne Newline
         */
        function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
            $output .= '</li>';
        }


        /**
         * Flache Struktur
         *
         * Wenn eine weitere Hierarchieebene beginnt, diese nicht mit einer weiteren UL verschachteln
         */
        function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) { }
        function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) { }
    }
```

And **the settings** for the  home-/news-/blog-page are as follows:

[image]

The "news"-page is a normal page without any content.

Now, when I want to see the details of a listed custom post type, I lose the menu items and I switch to the default blog menu.

**What I could do:**

- Whenever I save a custom post in the backend, I could add it programmatically as a new nav menu item to all the custom taxomomy-archive-menu-items to which it belongs (e.g. with `wp_update_nav_menu_object()`), but this would generate a huge menu, and when selecting a single building, would highlight several menu items which is not preferable.
- Whenever I click on the details button, I load the corresponding building by AJAX in order to keep the navigation untouched. But this seems a little bit unclean. In addition, the permalinks for a single building would display another navigation.

So, **how can I keep the current menu items when viewing a single building?** Once I achieve to keep the menu I will certainly be able to highlight the requested one.

I know, it's not yet a question with a precise code-relevant thing, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: How are you causing a different menu (taxonomy) to display on your custom post archives?

Comment: I added the taxonomy as a menu item. Not sure if I understood correctly.

Comment: In a typical WordPress installation, the menu is displayed using wp_nav_menu() in header.php. How are you getting one menu on some pages (your archive) and a different menu (the "default blog menu") on others?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the permalink for your single custom post (single building) is unrelated to the permalink for the taxonomy archive, so wp_nav_menu has no way of knowing that the single building page is related to that menu item.

I suggest the following approach:

1) In the template for your taxonomy archive, add a custom query parameter to each single-post link, e.g. ?customtax=taxonomy-slug.

2) Use the existence of this special parameter to cause your templates to use your custom Walker instead of the default blog menu

3) In your custom Walker, if this special parameter is present then give the menu entry corresponding to that taxonomy the class 'current_page_item'.